# How to apply suffix to multiple files in makefile?

Tags: makefile, emscripten

I want to apply a `--preload-file` suffix to multiple files at once.

If I do `--preload-file file1 --preload-file file2` then it works.

But if I do `--preload-file file1 file2`, then it generates the following error:

> file2: Input file has an unknown suffix, don't know what to do with
>   it!

Is there a way to apply the suffix to both files at once so I can do something like `--preload-file $(MY_FILES)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html?highlight=preload:

> `--preload-file <name>`
>
> Specify a file to preload before running the compiled code
>   asynchronously. The path is relative to the current directory at
>   compile time. If a directory is passed here, its entire contents will
>   be embedded.

So as long as file1 and file2 are under the same directory, you should be able to pass it, so the suffix will be applied, in your case, to both files.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an answer to the specific question, if you have GNU make you can use:

```
$(addprefix --preload-file ,$(MY_FILES))
```

(note the space before the comma).  There's no way to do it in POSIX standard make.